# Visual Studio - view type from metadata

Tags: visual-studio

I remember that in previous installations of Visual Studio that I had, when I used the 'go to definition' option on a type that was not in the current solution it would display a tab showing the type as reflected from metadata. My current installation goes directly to the Object Browser. I prefered seeing the metadata version.

Is there any way of choosing what the default behaviour is, or is this something that changed between versions of VS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have resharper installed, it changes the VS shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka!

*"The Code Definition window is a read-only editor view that displays the definition of a symbol in a code file stored in, or referenced by, the active project. To display this window, select Code Definition Window from the View menu. When the window first opens, it displays the definition for the last symbol selected. If no definition is available, No definition selected is displayed. This window can be docked along any convenient edge of the integrated development environment (IDE). By default, it is displayed beneath the Code Editor. "*

Comment: Am I right that this is from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5yx24a6.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To make this happen, the dll containing the class must be added as a reference in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Visual Studio 2005 this should be the default behavior for C# and I'm not aware of a way to change it.  Are you using VB.Net?  If so, going to the Object Browser is "By Design" and there is no way to change it.

**EDIT**

OP commented that C# is the language in question here so the VB.Net guess is incorrect.

Another option is to try and reset your settings to the C# defaults.  If there is a supported setting which changes the behavior, resetting to the default settings should undo the setting

- Tools -> Options -> Import / Export Settings
- Follow the steps to reset all settings
- Choose C# developer
- Restart VS

Comment: I use both, but I was referring to C# specifically